# Entity Framework 6 Context Lifetime

Tags: entity-framework

I have been reading everywhere that the 'right' way to use a context is the following:

```
using (var Db = new MyDatabase())
{
    DoStuff(Db);
}
```

But I have found this to be painfully slow in some cases.
I have a function that is called a lot, from different threads, through web requests and is READ ONLY.
This is my test code:

```
var S = new Stopwatch()
S.Start();
Parallel.For(
    0,
    15000,
    I =>
    {
        var P = GetPostWebContent(I);
    });

S.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(S.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

With the 'recommended' method the execution time is 303.6s for 15000 calls, 20.24ms per call.

Now, by keeping one context per thread, I get very different results, using the following code:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static MyDatabase _Db;
if (_Db == null) _Db = new DatabaseWebsite();
DoStuff(Db);
```

And the execution time is 52.4s for 15000 calls, 3.5ms per call.

Which means that this solution is 5.8x faster!

I am a little bit shocked: I keep reading online that the context creation is not a big deal, etc; but in my case, it has a huge impact.
I am aware that with this implementation the context will keep growing in size, but I could implement a counter and re-create the context regularly.
Is there anything that would prevent this from being used? As I said above, all the operation are READ ONLY, I am not writing anything to the database.

Comment: unfortunately, the vast majority of examples tend to gloss over things like memory management, resorting to the "if we throw in a `using` statement, the GC will just clean up behind us" attitude.  This is fine for examples or simple code, but you quickly learn you need a more robust strategy in many cases once you understand the basics of things.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a recommendation.  Context is not thread safe, so having one per thread is a good idea if performance is important for you.

I tend to pass contexts around methods that run on the same thread because I've found performance issues with creating contexts.  It's worked on production code for me.